# Музыкальный плеер - PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qmediaplayer

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в некоторых участках кода:

```
class MP3Player(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.state = "Play"
        self.playlist = []
        self.position = 0

        self.init_ui()
...
```

и

```
...

def play_mp3(self):
    if self.state == "Play":
        self.playbtn.setText("Pause")
        self.state = "Pause"
        path = self.songlist.currentItem().text()
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
        content = QMediaContent(url)
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setPosition(self.position)
        self.playlist.append(path)
        if len(self.playlist) > 2:
            self.playlist.pop(0)
        if self.songlist.currentItem().text() != self.playlist[0]:
            self.position = 0
            self.player.setPosition(self.position)
        self.player.play()
    else:
        self.playbtn.setText("Play")
        self.state = "Play"
        self.player.pause()
        paused = self.player.position()
        self.position = paused
...
```

Заранее спасибо.

Полный код:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent,QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QUrlQuery
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class MP3Player(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.state = "Play"
        self.playlist = []
        self.position = 0

        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):
        vb = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vb)
        vb.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


        self.label = QLabel("MP3 Player")
        self.label.setFont(QFont("Calibri",20 ))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        vb.addWidget(self.label)

        hb = QHBoxLayout()
        vb.addLayout(hb)

        font = QFont("Calibri", 14)
        self.backwardbtn = QPushButton()
        self.backwardbtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSeekBackward))
        hb.addWidget(self.backwardbtn)

        self.playbtn = QPushButton('Play',self)
        self.playbtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playbtn.setFont(font)
        hb.addWidget(self.playbtn)

        self.forwardbtn = QPushButton()
        self.forwardbtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSeekForward))
        self.forwardbtn.setFont(font)
        hb.addWidget(self.forwardbtn)


        hb2 = QHBoxLayout()
        vb.addLayout(hb2)

        self.openfilebtn = QPushButton()
        self.openfilebtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon))
        self.openfilebtn.setFont(font)
        hb2.addWidget(self.openfilebtn)

        self.slider = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setRange(0,0)
        self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)
        hb2.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.songlist = QListWidget()
        vb.addWidget(self.songlist)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar()
        vb.addWidget(self.toolbar)

        self.openfileaction = QAction()
        self.openfileaction.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon))
        self.openfileaction.setFont(font)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.openfileaction)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()

        self.openfilebtn.clicked.connect(self.open_mp3_file)
        self.playbtn.clicked.connect(self.play_mp3)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.position_changed)
        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.duration_changed)
        self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)
        self.backwardbtn.clicked.connect(self.move_backward)
        self.forwardbtn.clicked.connect(self.move_forward)


    def open_mp3_file(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog()
        file_name.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
        names = file_name.getOpenFileNames(self,"Open files", os.getenv("HOME"))
        self.song = names[0]
        self.songlist.addItems(self.song)


    def play_mp3(self):
        if self.state == "Play":
            self.playbtn.setText("Pause")
            self.state = "Pause"
            path = self.songlist.currentItem().text()
            url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
            content = QMediaContent(url)
            self.player.setMedia(content)
            self.player.setPosition(self.position)
            self.playlist.append(path)
            if len(self.playlist) > 2:
                self.playlist.pop(0)
            if self.songlist.currentItem().text() != self.playlist[0]:
                self.position = 0
                self.player.setPosition(self.position)
            self.player.play()
        else:
            self.playbtn.setText("Play")
            self.state = "Play"
            self.player.pause()
            paused = self.player.position()
            self.position = paused

    def set_position(self, position):
        self.player.setPosition(position)


    def position_changed(self,position):
        self.slider.setValue(position)

    def duration_changed(self, duration):
        self.slider.setRange(0, duration)

    def state_changed(self, state):
        if self.player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playbtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playbtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def move_forward(self):
        self.player.setPosition(int(self.player.position()) + 2000)

    def move_backward(self):
        self.player.setPosition(int(self.player.position()) - 2000)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MP3Player()
    gui.setGeometry(600,200,600,700)
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ну вы хоть как-то пометьте эти строки комментариями или чем. Предлагаете вручную нам строки считать?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MP3Player(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #насследование инициализации от родительского класса, т.е. QWidget

        self.state = "Play" # атрибуту state присваивается "Play"
        self.playlist = [] # создается пустой список
        self.position = 0 # еще один атрибут

        self.init_ui() # вызывается метод (функция) init_ui()
```

```
def play_mp3(self): # эта функция вызывается когда надо остановить или продолжить воспроизведение
    if self.state == "Play": # если сейчас музыка играет ...
        self.playbtn.setText("Pause") # ... кнопка проигрывания меняется на Паузу
        self.state = "Pause" # атрибут state меняется на "Pause"
        path = self.songlist.currentItem().text() # вызывается метод currentItem, возвращаемое значение присваивается переменной path
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path) # также вызов метода с параметром path
        content = QMediaContent(url) # вызов метода с параметром url
        self.player.setMedia(content) # опять метод
        self.player.setPosition(self.position) # и снова метод
        self.playlist.append(path) # значение path добавляется в список playlist
        if len(self.playlist) > 2: # если длина списка playlist больше 2...
            self.playlist.pop(0) # ... первое значение выкидываем
        if self.songlist.currentItem().text() != self.playlist[0]: # если возвращаемое методом currentItem() значение не равно первому элементу playlist...
            self.position = 0 # тут понятно
            self.player.setPosition(self.position) # и тут понятно
        self.player.play() # включение музыки видимо
    else: # если музыка сейчас в паузе
        self.playbtn.setText("Play") # кнопка проигрывания меняется на Плэй
        self.state = "Play" # состояние проигрывателя тоже становится Плэй
        self.player.pause() # нажимается паузка
        paused = self.player.position() # и сохраняется состояние
        self.position = paused # а позиция указывается как "в паузе"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MP3Player(QWidget):         
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # создаем объекты как атрибуты класса, 
        # которые будем использовать в любых методах класса
        self.state = "Play"
        self.playlist = []
        self.position = 0

        self.init_ui()            # вызов метода init_ui() 
                                  #                v
                                  #                v
    def init_ui(self):  #  <-----------------------<
        ...
```

Описание класса из которого вы создаете экземпляр (`gui = MP3Player()`),
который будет главным окном приложения.

Метод `__init__` - конструктор класса. 
В объектно-ориентированном программировании конструктором класса
называют метод, который автоматически вызывается при создании объектов. 
Его также можно назвать конструктором объектов класса. 
В *Python* наличие пар знаков подчеркивания спереди и сзади
в имени метода говорит о том, что он принадлежит к группе методов
перегрузки операторов.

При этом методы перегрузки операторов не надо вызывать по имени.
Вызовом для них является сам факт участия объекта в определенной операции. 
В случае конструктора класса – это операция создания объекта.
Так как объект создается в момент вызова класса по имени,
то в этот момент вызывается метод `__init__()`.

Необходимость конструкторов связана с тем, что нередко объекты должны иметь
собственные свойства сразу, которые будут использоваться в разных методах.

---

```
def play_mp3(self):                                   
    if self.state == "Play":
        self.playbtn.setText("Pause")
        self.state = "Pause"
        path = self.songlist.currentItem().text()
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
        content = QMediaContent(url)
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setPosition(self.position)
        self.playlist.append(path)
        if len(self.playlist) > 2:
            self.playlist.pop(0)
        if self.songlist.currentItem().text() != self.playlist[0]:
            self.position = 0
            self.player.setPosition(self.position)
        self.player.play()
    else:
        self.playbtn.setText("Play")
        self.state = "Play"
        self.player.pause()
        paused = self.player.position()
        self.position = paused
```

Это метод, который вызывается по нажатию кнопки `self.playbtn`:

```
self.playbtn.clicked.connect(self.play_mp3)
```

В этом методе мы проверяем значение объекта `self.state`,
которому в конструкторе класса было первоначально присвоено значение
`self.state = "Play"`.

В зависимости от текущего значение `self.state` мы начинаем проигрывать музыку `self.player.play()` 
или если значение `self.state` отлично от **`"Play"`** мы
ставим проигрыватель на паузу `self.player.pause()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]